# Use Google Maps Places JS API to get details about a list of places

Tags: google-places-api

I am trying to get place details on a large number of places through the google maps places js api.

When I try to do single place lookups, I get back about 8 and then OVER_QUOTA errors.

I would like to know if there is a way to ask for details about a list of places to reduce the load.

Comment: You may be hitting max for per minute limit.

Comment: I am.  Is there any way to request the details all at once?  Because I am not allowed to store information from the places API, I have to do each lookup on the page, correct?

Comment: There is an API I am using that should help you. This will take care of your limit per minute request. https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java. It will not limit your daily request max. Max fetch from Google is 150,000 request.

Comment: @java_dude - thanks, that seems like an implementation of the server side API.  That seems to have a low daily limit compared to the web api: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

"Server-side geocoding through the Geocoding Web Service has a quota of 2,500 requests per IP per day"

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage Read - Usage limits

Comment: That may work, I'll have to look into that, thanks!

Add your suggestion as an answer, and I'll accept it.